# Not able to connect to mongodb using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

If I try connecting using the mongo driver from the rails console, it works fine:

```
client = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://username:password@dds-xxxxxxxx.mongodb.singapore.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717,dds-xxxxxxxx.mongodb.singapore.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717/graspire?replicaSet=mgset-xxxxxxx')
client.database.collection(:courses).count
```

The above code works fine and gives me the result. However if from the rails console i do:

```
Course.count
```

Then i get this error:

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No server is available matching preference: #<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x52072480 tag_sets=[] max_staleness=nil> using server_selection_timeout=30 and local_threshold=0.015
```

This is my mongoid.yml

```
production:
  # Configure available database clients. (required)
  clients:
    # Defines the default client. (required)
    default:
      uri: mongodb://username:password@dds-xxxxxxxx.mongodb.singapore.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717,dds-xxxxxxxx.mongodb.singapore.rds.aliyuncs.com:3717/graspire?replicaSet=mgset-xxxxxxx
  options:
```

Using mongoid version- 6.1.0, mongo version - 2.4.1

Comment: Which mongoid version?

Comment: mongoid version- 6.1.0, mongo version - 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

How do you running you Rails console?. Without specifying enviroment, rails console by default runs in development. Please check if your development group in defined inside mongoid.yml.

Comment: I start in the production environment only using - "rails c production"

Comment: Can you run below command in console?                                                                                 Mongoid.load!("config/mongoid.yml", :production)

Comment: Is Your Mongodb server started. Please check your mongodb server.

Comment: Yeah, that Mongoid.load! did the trick. I had it inside the application class in application.rb earlier. Thanks!!